# AWS CloudFormation identify IP of another instance - circular dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm provisioning two instances with CloudFormation template. "MASTER" and "SLAVE".

At the userdata script I need to pass slave's private IP to master and master's IP to slave.

Here is my template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Description" : "",
  "Parameters" : {
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Default Ports",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ 
        { "IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"}
         ]
         }
         },
      "MASTER" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "Tags":[{"Key":"Name", "Value":"MASTER"}],
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "KeyName" : "mykey",
        "ImageId" : "ami-a25415cb",
        "InstanceType": "m1.large",
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -ex", "\n",
          "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/bootstrap.sh","\n",
          "ROLE=MASTER SLAVEIP=",?????," sh bootstrap.sh","\n"
         ] ] } }
      }
      },
      "SLAVE" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "Tags":[{"Key":"Name", "Value":"SLAVE"}],
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "KeyName" : "mykey",
        "ImageId" : "ami-a25415cb",
        "InstanceType": "m1.large",
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -ex", "\n",
          "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/bootstrap.sh","\n",
          "ROLE=SLAVE MASTERIP=",?????," sh bootstrap.sh","\n"
         ] ] } }
      }
      },
  },
  "Outputs" : {
  }

}
```

What would be right replacement for ????? if it's possible at all and if not - what alternative can I use?

UPD: found this: {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MASTER","PrivateIp"]}, it works fine on it's own, but fails with "Template validation error: Circular dependency between resources: [SLAVE, MASTER]" if I'm trying to do both master and slave IPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using VPCs and Subnets, you can do this by creating an `AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface` for each instance. Then use `{ "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MyNetworkInterface", "PrimaryPrivateIpAddress" ] }` in user data to reference the internal IP address of the network interface

You associate a network interface with an EC2 instance using the `NetworkInterfaces` property

```
...
"MasterNetInt" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
  "Properties" : {
    "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "MySubnet" }
  }
},
"SlaveNetInt" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
  "Properties" : {
    "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "MySubnet" }
  }
},


"Master" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
    "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
    "KeyName" : "mykey",
    "ImageId" : "ami-a25415cb",
    "InstanceType": "m1.large",
    "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "MySubnet" },
    "NetworkInterfaces": [ { "Ref" : "MasterNetInt" } ],
    "UserData": { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash -ex", "\n",
      "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/bootstrap.sh","\n",
      "ROLE=MASTER SLAVEIP=", { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SlaveNetInt", "PrimaryPrivateIpAddress" ] }," sh bootstrap.sh","\n"
     ] ] } }
  }
},
"Slave" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
    "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
    "KeyName" : "mykey",
    "ImageId" : "ami-a25415cb",
    "InstanceType": "m1.large",
    "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "MySubnet" },
    "NetworkInterfaces": [ { "Ref" : "SlaveNetInt" } ],
    "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash -ex", "\n",
      "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/bootstrap.sh","\n",
      "ROLE=SLAVE MASTERIP=", { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "MasterNetInt", "PrimaryPrivateIpAddress" ] }," sh bootstrap.sh","\n"
     ] ] } }
  }
}
...
```

If you're unfamiliar with setting up a VPC and Subnets, read the following documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html

and reference these template examples: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-services-us-west-2.html#d0e113371

The basic requirements are:

```
AWS::EC2::VPC
AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
AWS::EC2::RouteTable
AWS::EC2::Route
AWS::EC2::Subnet
AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl
AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry

AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
AWS::EC2::Instance
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I actually figured out how to build required configuration only knowing slave's IP on a master, so all set for now, but would keep your suggestion for the next projects.